# Error writing in a log file using logcat comand programatically. Using exec command

Tags: android, file, logging, exec

I have been a lot of troubles creating a log file. It worked for me in another program but not in this one and I'm getting crazy because I wrote exactly the same... 
I want to store the logcat in a .txt file in the SDCard in an Android device. It creates the file but it is empty.

The code:

```
public void logging() throws IOException{
    Log.i(TAG, "On logging");
    String listLogs = "dalvikm:I System.err:I AndroidRuntime:I NetworkInfo:I ActivityManager:I ";
    File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/logEth.txt");      
    try {
        filename.createNewFile();
        String cmd = "logcat -d -v threadtime -f "+ filename.getAbsolutePath() +" "+ listLogs +" *:S";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);     
        Log.d(TAG, "logs written");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, " on creating logging ", e);
        throw new IOException(TAG+" error creating the logs. ", e);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: No, not error at all. And I get "logs written" message after the Runtime function.

Comment: Did you add the required permission in the manifest file ?

Comment: Yes, actually the file is created without errors.

Comment: I think there are some restrictions in later Android versions on which processes can access logcat output.

Comment: If you are using JB+ Android OS you will need a root device to save a logcat, if not, your code should work. What OS are you using?

Comment: I really don't understand why it doesn't work. 
I'm using 4.0.3 in a tablet.
The point is that it works fine in another application >_<

Comment: Someone else in StackOverflow had one of the permissions off by a letter, got no complaints from the OS but had problems.  Did you spell them exactly right?  `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_LOGS`